# Not able to recover logical partition using TestDisk

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, partition-recovery, testdisk, logical-drive

I had a dual-booted HDD (Win10 and Ubuntu) (MBR) where the Ubuntu was in an extended partition (that had 1 Win10 logical partition and 1 Ubuntu logical partition).

Few months ago, **I deleted that Ubuntu logical partition and expanded Win10 logical partition to cover full extended partition space.**

The disks now look like this

[image]

Now I am needing some files that were on Ubuntu parition and I tried to recover them from TestDisk. **Happily, TestDisk recovered that same previous partition table as shown.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, I select that Linux partition and attempt to Write but **there is a Write error**. The only problematic thing I am seeing in log file is this

```
Error: size boot_sector 291971072 > partition 188743680
check_part_i386 failed for partition type 07
     HPFS - NTFS          42626 178 49 54375 115 12  188743680

recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/393, s_mnt_count=34/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 12903424
recover_EXT2: part_size 103227392
Filesystem created: Sat Feb 20 12:28:58 2021
Last mount time:    Sun Aug 15 14:52:52 2021
     Linux                54375 147 45 60801  47 46  103227392
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB, 52 GB / 49 GiB

Results
   * HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    63 221 30    1024000 [System Reserved]
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 524 MB / 500 MiB
   P HPFS - NTFS             63 221 31 16497 247  6  264013824
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 135 GB / 125 GiB
   P HPFS - NTFS          16498  21 60 42626 143 38  419753985
     NTFS, blocksize=4096, 214 GB / 200 GiB
   L HPFS - NTFS          42626 178 49 54375 115 12  188743680
   L Linux                54375 147 45 60801  47 46  103227392
     ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB, 52 GB / 49 GiB
add_ext_part_i386: max
add_ext_part_i386: max

interface_write()
 1 * HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    63 221 30    1024000 [System Reserved]
 2 P HPFS - NTFS             63 221 31 16497 247  6  264013824
 3 P HPFS - NTFS          16498  21 60 42626 143 38  419753985
 4 E extended LBA         42626 146 17 60801  80 15  291977216
 5 L HPFS - NTFS          42626 178 49 54375 115 12  188743680
 6 L Linux                54375 147 45 60801  47 46  103227392
```

Please suggest me how can I recover that partition. (without data loss)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message looks weird.. is there a TestDisk forum or mailing list or bug tracker?

Comment: @golimar what is the weird thing. there is a forum https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/index.php

Comment: This contribution is a cross-posting of 
https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=11793

Comment: @r2d3 that is a cross-post of this question btw and the reason is well-understandable. And this is not a relaunch of that other question at all however the goal is same.

Answer (score 1):

Gladly the issue has been resolved with full data recovery.

I deleted that whole Win10 logical partition **(Caution: not the extended partition)** and then the Write was successful and asked to reboot. My whole Ubuntu dual boot has been recovered exactly as it was.

I got a hint about this from the error in log file

```
Error: size boot_sector 291971072 > partition 188743680
```

and deduced that the already present Windows 10 partition which needed to shrink could be the issue. It could also have been an issue due to boot files of Ubuntu. At the end, the problem seemed to be unavailability of free space.